# Setting Telerik RadTreeView attributes such as OnClientNodeExpanded via Javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik, radtreeview

I have a RadTreeView which that can eb referenced by the variable:  *TV*

I did not know if i could just do jQuery to do $(TV).attr("OnClientNodeExpanded","newvalue") because there might be a server side link that i may be unaware of.

When I defined my RadTreeView in the markup, it has 2 attributes:  OnClientNodeExpanded and OnClientNodeClicked which are set to some javascript functions.

My question is as follows:

Is there a way to change where both OnClientNodeExpanded and OnClientNodeClicked point by some reference like:  *TV.set_ClientNodeExpanded("NEW_FUNCTION");*

I want to depending on what is clicked have the RadTreeView populate different material.

Edit to help clarify my goal: *The asp.net control has those attributes.  Which means that the functions, are actually loadNode and clickedNode. What i was wanting to do was to change the reference of those attributes listed above to point to a different function. I wasnt sure i wanted to have an intermediate "judging" function to determine what functions were to be called, but instead a way to override the current declaration as to what fires when the RadTreeView Event Occurs. Does that clarify?*

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript `OnClientNodeClicked` function, you can check which item was clicked and then call the function you want.

```
function OnClientNodeClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
    var node = eventArgs.get_node();

    if(yourConditionHere){
        callFunctionA();
    }
    else{
        callFunctionB();
    }
}
```

Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Not quite, the asp.net control has those attributes.

    <tekerik:RadTreeView OnClientNodeExpanded="loadNode" OnClientNodeClicked="clickedNode"></telerik:RadTreeView>

Which means that the functions, are actually loadNode and clickedNode.  What i was wanting to do was to change the reference of those attributes listed above to point to a different function.  I wasnt sure i wanted to have an intermediate "judging" function to determine what functions were to be called, but instead a way to override the current declaration as to what fires when the RadTreeView Event Occurs.  Does that clarify?

Comment: I see what you mean now. But I doubt it is possible... Have you tried attaching the "onclick" attribute over each node element (from the `OnNodeDataBound` server Event)?

Comment: no.  Each of the attributes above has its own events under the circumstances in which they are fires.  The Documentation for everything, events and what i am trying to do is located at: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-events.html  I just cant find it, and i figure it might be located in a spot i overlooked.